# Naive Euclidean algorithm - average complexity?

Tags: computer-science, recursion

Suppose I compute the GCD in a rather simple-minded recursive way:
$$
\gcd(a, b) = 
\begin{cases}
\gcd(a, b-a) & \text{ if }{a < b}, \\
\gcd(a-b, b) & \text{ if }{a > b}, \\
a & \text{ if } {a = b}.
\end{cases}
$$

In the worst-case scenario, this may take about $\max\{a,b\}$ steps - just put $a = 1$ and take large $b$. What I am curious about is the *average* case.

If $a,b$ are chosen uniformly at random from $[1,n]$, what can be said about the expected number of recursive steps?

(My main motivation is just idle curiousity.)